# How to remove session id in c# and in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to hide session id in the header request?

[image: image of header]

Comment: Don't use session state.

Comment: **Why** do you want to "hide" it? Or do you just want to remove it because you're not using it?

Comment: Do you want to hide while running session or remove it after logout from session? If you want to remove it after log off you can check here:https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/134945/Remove-Delete-ASPNETSessionId-Cookie-from-browser-after-Logout-using-C-in-ASPNet/

Comment: You can see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865185/asp-net-sessionid-cookie-how-it-work